# Is the equality $(A \Delta B) \Delta B = A$ true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've generated online two sets with different elements (except for $37$ and $22$):
$A = \{10, 14, 20, 22, 25, 31, 37\}$
$B = \{5, 17, 22, 37, 38, 42, 45\}$

I've divided the problem in two steps. The first step

1. $A \Delta B$, which is $\{10,14,20,25,31,5,17,38,42,45\}$

and the second step

2. $(A \Delta B) \Delta B = \{10,14,20,22,25,31,37\}$

And with the two steps we proved that the equality is a lie, BUT I'm not sure if this is correct and if it is not, how can I prove it without elements.

Comment: The equality is a lie? That is surely a mistranslation? You have shown that in this case, the equality is _true_.

Comment: But is this the trivial way of proving this and also any equality or is it just in this case true (with these numbers).

Comment: You verified an example, you did not actually prove that for **all** $A$ and $B$ you have $(A\triangle B)\triangle B = A$. To prove that, one usually uses the fact that $X\triangle X=\varnothing$ for all $X$, that $Y\triangle \varnothing = Y$ for all $Y$, and that $(X\triangle Y)\triangle Z = X\triangle(Y\triangle Z)$ for any sets $X$, $Y$, and~$Z$.

Comment: I agree with @TonyK, the equality is true, as you can [check here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=is+%28A+symmetric+difference+B%29+symmetric+difference+B+%3D+A).

Comment: Note that $A \Delta B = \{x | x \in A \operatorname{XOR}  x \in B\}$ so $(A \Delta B) \Delta B$ = A is equivalent to $(a \operatorname{XOR} b) \operatorname{XOR} b = a$ which can be verified with a truth table.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, it can be helpful to consider what happens to a generic element.

Let's say that $a \in A$ and $a \notin B$ (equivalently, $a \in A \setminus B$). Then $a \in A \Delta B$ (by definition of $\Delta$), and from there it follows that $a \in (A \Delta B) \Delta B$. Since we imposed no other conditions on $a$, it follows that *every* element of $A \setminus B$ is an element of $(A \Delta B) \Delta B$.

We still have to consider three other generic elements:

- Let $b \in B \setminus A$.
- Let $c \in A \cap B$.
- Let $d \notin A \cup B$

You can convince yourself that there are no other generic elements to consider by applying the [law of the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) - each object is either an element of A, or not, and separately it is either an element of B, or not, so we just have to consider four cases in total.

The arguments for these elements are similar but not identical to the argument for $a$ (exercise for the reader: try writing those arguments yourself!). We ultimately end up with $a$ and $c$ in the final set, and $b$ and $d$ not in the final set, which means that the final set contains all and only those elements which were originally in A. That was the result to be proved, so we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, A Δ B = (A ∪ B) − (A ∩ B). So, if you expand, you will get this:

(A Δ B ∪ B) − (A Δ B ∩ B)

Given that A Δ B deletes the intersection, A Δ B ∪ B retrieves this intersection, changing it to just A ∪ B.

A ∪ B − (A Δ B ∩ B)

With the same thought in mind, (A Δ B ∩ B) will be just A - B.

Now it's just A ∪ B − (A - B), and this is equals to B, so yeah, you are right.